# Android API integration and development

Tags: android

I need exact android coding for this screenshots, Since i am new to android development i don't know much about this concept.

```
    I had posted three screens with an xml files and API links:
    1) My MainActivity
    2) My getVehicle Listview
    3) My screenshots from postman's response
    [1) My postman's response][1]
    [2) My Main Activity][2]
    [3) My addVehicleListview][3]

        [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmj86.png``
        [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCa5s.png
        [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vjxC.png

    There is no problem about the design files..i had posted the design files for your reference.
     The problem is that i need to pass the user's id and imei of the user's mobile as a header params in my http java class to get the response as like in my addVehicleListView screen.

     I very kindly request all my friends to post me the exact coding which consists of 2 java files namely
    1] mainActivity
    2] GetVehicleListView
    3] httpfile
    Below is my API links for adding vehicle and fetching it back by passing id and imei as a header parameters.

    add: http://garage.kaptastech.mobi/api/5k/master/vehicle
    fetch: http://garage.kaptastech.mobi/api/5k/users/vehicle
```

I had posted my 2 xml codings for your reference for the ids.
    My xml coding:
    activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parentLay"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/addVehicletoolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/slightgrey3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:background="@color/White"
            android:id="@+id/VehicleLayout">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/vehilayA3"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:text="@string/vehicleRegno"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:id="@+id/textView8" />



                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0.3dp"
                    android:id="@+id/View2"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:background="@color/slightgrey">
                </View>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp">


                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:hint="@string/VehicleRegNumber"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:theme="@style/MyEditTextTheme"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/slightgrey2"
                        android:id="@+id/AddVehicle_Regno" />

                    <!--   <TextView
                           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:textSize="8sp"
                           android:text="kilometer reading"
                           android:layout_weight="1"
                           android:id="@+id/textViewkms" /> -->

                </LinearLayout>



            </LinearLayout>



            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/typelay"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="25dp">



                <RadioGroup
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="1">


                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Petrol"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:id="@+id/petrol"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />


                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Diesel"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:id="@+id/diesel"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />
                </RadioGroup>


                <!--  <CheckBox
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text="Petrol"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:id="@+id/petrol" />

                  <CheckBox
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text="Disel"
                      android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:id="@+id/disel" />  -->
                <!-- <Spinner
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="40dp"
                     android:id="@+id/AddspinnerType"
                     android:layout_weight="1"
                     android:prompt="@string/type"
                     android:layout_gravity="center"
                     android:entries="@array/type"
                     android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                     android:background="@drawable/select_spinner"/>  -->

            </LinearLayout>

            <!--  <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/View1"
                android:background="@color/slightgrey">
            </View>  -->


            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/vehilayA1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:visibility="visible"  >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >


                    <!--  <ImageView
                          android:layout_width="24dp"
                          android:layout_height="24dp"
                          android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                          android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                          android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                          android:layout_gravity="center"
                          android:src="@drawable/circle"/>
       -->
                    <Spinner
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:id="@+id/AddspinnerMake"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:prompt="@string/brand"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:entries="@array/brand"
                        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                        android:background="@drawable/select_spinner"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <!--   <View
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="0.3dp"
                       android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                       android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                       android:id="@+id/View5"
                       android:background="@color/slightgrey">
                   </View>  -->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="25dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1dp" >


                        <!--  <ImageView
                              android:layout_width="24dp"
                              android:layout_height="24dp"
                              android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                              android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                              android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                              android:layout_gravity="center"
                              android:src="@drawable/circle"/>  -->

                        <Spinner
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:id="@+id/AddspinnerModel"
                            android:prompt="@string/Model"
                            android:entries="@array/Model"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                            android:background="@drawable/select_spinner2"/>

                        <Spinner
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:id="@+id/AddspinnerYear"
                            android:prompt="@string/Year"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:entries="@array/Year"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                            android:background="@drawable/select_spinner2"/>
                    </LinearLayout>





                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

            <!--  <View
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="0.3dp"
                  android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                  android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                  android:id="@+id/View6"
                  android:background="@color/slightgrey">
              </View>  -->



            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/variantlay"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="25dp">



                <RadioGroup
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="1">


                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Fully Loaded"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:id="@+id/fullyLoaded"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />


                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Basic Model"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:id="@+id/basicmodel"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />
                </RadioGroup>


                <!--<CheckBox
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Fully Loaded"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/fullyloaded" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Basic Model"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/basicmodel" />
                <Spinner
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="40dp"
                     android:id="@+id/AddspinnerType"
                     android:layout_weight="1"
                     android:prompt="@string/type"
                     android:layout_gravity="center"
                     android:entries="@array/type"
                     android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                     android:background="@drawable/select_spinner"/>  -->

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:text="Kms Covered"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textViewkms" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?           android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:hint="123456"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:theme="@style/MyEditTextTheme"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/slightgrey2"
                    android:id="@+id/kmsCovered" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/addVBtn"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_bg_red"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:id="@+id/addVehicleBtn" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

2) My activty_list

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/parentLay"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/addVehiclestoolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:divider="@color/SlightWhite2">

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/addVehicleListView"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:divider="@color/white"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

So friends i have posted my problems with details...please post me the exact tutorial.Or in case of posting link,please post me the links which will be most similar to my problem.

please help me friends..Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to these links for tutorials related to accessing web service in your android app.
1) http://www.javatpoint.com/android-web-service 2)http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

1)As mentioned in 1st link you can send the user_id and imei code and fetch your Jsondata in response and than

2)you can parse that data in proper string format to display in your MainActivity which is given in 2nd link.

You can access your device's imei code with :

TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

String devieID = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();

Comment: androholic, thanx.. and first of all i need to convey you that i had already tried the above two links. but it shows and ends up with blank white screen

Comment: @Arun are you able to get the data as response or is it throwing an Exception ?

Comment: its not thrrowiing any exception, it ends up with an white screen alone,since its impossible to execute with the emulator. i had executed in my device

Comment: @Arun You can debug your code and see what is the reason behind the "blank screen" , we will be able to help you if we know what the problem actually is.